# how to restore data after factory reset on cynogenmod one plus 1?

Tags: backup, restore

I have done factory reset of my mobile phone

One plus 1 (Cynogenmod)

Is there any way to get my lost data(photos,videos) back?

Comment: Factory reset doesn't include /data/media and thus doesn't remove data from internal storage.

Comment: If you didn't select to wipe internal/external sd during factory reset, files should be in phone, but if you did than they are bye bye forever.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје i got few file using Aiseesoft Android Data Recovery